# What does מיללעליכט mean in this Responsa?

Tags: translation, lighting, responsa

In Shu"t HaElef Lecha Shlomo 1:116 it mentions a type of light called מיללעליכט and I am having a hard time deciphering what type of light it is. Only thing that came up was a light bulb called the light mill, but the year it came out doesnt seem to correspond with [Rav Shlomo Kluger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Kluger)'s age. It also seems that it is in the candle family, but something different. Anyone have an idea?

Text of responsum:

> שאלה בדין אם מותר ללמוד בליל ש"ק נגד **מיללעליכט** נראה דמותר דלא שייך לומר לא פלוג במה דהוי לו שם מיוחד בפ"ע דודאי בנר שאין לו שם מיוחד רק בסתם נראה בזה שייך לומר לא פלוג אף דלא שייך בי' הגזרה שמא יטה אבל בנר דיש לו שם מיוחד כגון נר שעוה או נר **מיללעליכט** כוין דיש לו שם לוי בפ"ע לא שייך בזה לא פלוג ומותר ללמוד אצלו בלי חשש ופקפוק כלל:‏

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Dr. Shmuel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16706/dr-shmuel) mentioned in a comment, this section is quoted [here](https://www.steinsaltz-center.org.il/vault/RabBrandesShiur/5gzerot.pdf) on page 24 footnote 86.

There he elaborates:

> ר' שלמה קלוגר מצא שני כוונים אחרים של היתר ללמוד לאור הנר בליל שבת. התיר בנר 
>   שבעששית זכוכית, כיון שהזכוכית מהוה היכר לאיסור ההטיה (שו"ת האלף לך שלמה או"ח קט"ו) והתיר בנר שיש לו "שם לוואי", כגון 'נר שעוה' או **'מיללעליכט**', כיון שהוא נבדל מנר רגיל וזה עצמו הוי כעין היכר. מאבי מורי ז"ל שמעתי, שהיו רגילים להתקין נרות עבים ללילי שבת בחורף, והיה רגיל בצעירותו לקרוא לאור הנר שעות רבות, בלילי שבתות, בעמידה.  ‏

#### It seems that it's a (long burning) wax candle. Thus, מיללעליכט is simply a synonym for נר שעוה.

There still is a *[Müller Kerzenfabrik](https://www.mueller-kerzen.de/en/about-mueller/about-us/)* (translation: Muller Candle factory) founded in Patschkau, Silesia (today Poland) in 1744.

So it's possible that wax candles were called Muller-candles, along the lines of Xerox, Frigidaire and other such genericized trademarks or proprietary eponyms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I asked someone after I posted this question who is involved with chassidim ,and told me that it indeed is a long candle used on Yom Kippur and during the seder . So basically like you mentioned a taller wax candle.

Comment: +1 - I sent an email to the Muller Candle factory asking for information.

Comment: "בנר שיש לו 'שם לוואי', כגון 'נר שעוה' או 'מיללעליכט" does not sound to me like he's saying those are synonyms, merely that they're both "[something] lamps".